# Did Mark Zuckerberg answer a question in similar circumstances to this?

Tags: historical-accuracy, the-social-network

In the Social Network, Mark Zuckerberg (played by Jesse Eisenberg) answers a question in a lecture:

Now I know this most likely is just the clique scene to make Zuckerberg seem so smart while he is obviously leaving in response to the message on the piece of paper.

But the question is, if he may actually have answered a question after leaving mid way through a class (and I highly doubt it was due to someone calling him names on a piece of paper) and the Professor made a remark similar to in the movie.

### So does anyone know if this scene has any truth to it?

It just seems too Hollywood for me.

Comment: A *clique* is an exclusionary group, usually of friends, like the popular kids in high school. A *cliche* is an overused concept or trope. I wonder if you meant the latter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this blog post by the professor](http://matt-welsh.blogspot.be/2010/10/in-defense-of-mark-zuckerberg.html) who is depicted in that scene:

> in fact **there is a scene where I'm shown teaching the Operating Systems course** (in a commanding performance by Brian Palermo -- my next choice was Brad Pitt, but I'm thrilled that Brian was available for the role). **The scene even shows my actual lecture notes on virtual memory.** Of course, **the content of the scene is completely fictional -- Mark Zuckerberg never stormed out of my class** (and I wouldn't have humiliated him for it if he had) -- although the bored, glazed-over look of the students in the scene was pretty much accurate.

Comment: I like this guy already.